# My input field is cleared automatically after four digits

Tags: html

I am trying to convert integers to Indian currency and return them back to the same input tag but it works well for four digits after that when I enter the fifth digit it again starts from the fifth digit. Please help me out. I am new to StackOverflow.

```
function currency(element) {
            let ele = document.getElementById(element.id);
            let num = ele.value
            let number = (parseInt(num))||0;
            console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-IN'));
            var int = number.toLocaleString('en-IN');
            document.getElementById(element.id).value = int.toString();
        }
```

it gives output `1,234` for `1234` 
but when I enter `12345` it returns `1` to the input tag

Comment: Purely from the code you've shown, the problem is not apparent. `parseInt('12345').toLocaleString('en-IN')` gives 12,345.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you type `1234`, your function changes the `<input>`'s value to `1,234`. But when you type a `5`, your function tries to read an integer from `1,2345`. The comma isn't a valid digit in base 10, so `parseInt` stops parsing at `1` ([step 13 in the `parseInt` algorithm](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-parseint-string-radix)). You'll need to sanitize the `<input>`'s value before passing it to `parseInt`:

```
let num = ele.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); // remove all non-digits from num
let number = (parseInt(num))||0;
```